# extjs - change url of xmlTreeLoader and reload?

Tags: extjs

I'm using extJs and I got a xmlTreeLoader:

```
filterTreeLoader = new Ext.app.BookLoader({
    dataUrl:'sampledata/xml-tree-data.xml'
})
```

Now I want to change the dataUrl ar runtime and reload the tree. I can change the dataUrl, but how do I make a refresh? Can't see a proper method on the extJs api...

```
        Ext.getCmp('tfProcChainDesc').setValue('TESvfdT');
    // Change the dataUrl
    filterTreeLoader.dataUrl = 'sampledata/xml-tree-data.xml';
    // How to refresh here?
```

PS: BookLoader extends TreeLoader, so I searched this api...
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [`TreeLoader.load()`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/TreeLoader.html#method-Ext.tree.TreeLoader-load)?